# How to set compile flag /bigobj in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have a cpp file that contains a huge array.

I get a fatal error (exceeded object file format limit) and the suggestion to compile with the flag  /bigobj

Where do I set this flag in visual studio?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the Command Line property page as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173499%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 21):

According to MSDN and [/bigobj (Increase Number of Sections in .Obj file)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173499.aspx):

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development
>   environment
>
> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see [How to: Open Project Property Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e79xc5h1.aspx).
> 2. Click the C/C++ folder.
> 3. Click the Command Line property page.
> 4. Type the compiler option in the Additional Options box.

Comment: It's disgusting that you have to use the command line to add a flag mentioned by the VC compiler - thanks for adding the link to MSDN to verify.

Comment: @MikeSadler It is quite amazing how you interpreted "Command Line property page" wrongly.

Comment: Note that this is slightly overkill. On the **project** page, you set this option for every .cpp file in the project. The question wonders about a single .cpp file. In Visual Studio, this Command Line property page is also available at individual file level.