# error C1083: Cannot open source file: '/bigobj': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, flags

In Visual Studio 2013, I had to set the /bigobj flag on one of my projects because it would not compile otherwise. I rebuilt the solution, and this error appears :

Error   1299    error C1083: Cannot open source file: '/bigobj': No such file or directory

The problem is, /bigobj is not a file, it is a compiler option added to the "Additional options" box in the "Command Line" section of the "C/C++ Properties" of my project.

Why does Visual Studio think it is a file ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173499.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set compile flag /bigobj in visual studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225078/how-to-set-compile-flag-bigobj-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I am not asking how to set the /bigobj compile property, I already did that. Now the compiler says he cannot find /bigobj file. Why ?

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong. Whatever you've done it's causing the compiler to pick it up as a file instead of a command line option.

Comment: I followed the procedure described here : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173499.aspx

Comment: Can you tell me what I did wrong ?